# get main KPI evolution from graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Using graph API, i am able to get the current information i want to gather about a user/page/etc.

I am wondering if it is possible to gather data from the Graph API for a precise date ?
I would like at the end to have a graph with the evolution of one KPI.

Example : How many followers did someone have yesterday at 2.30PM GMT ?

Comment: there is not even any api to get the followers of a user...and about pages: is it about pages you manage?

Comment: Let's say that i have all access that i need.
And let's say that it's my publication.
Is it possible to get the number of likes that i got the 20 October 2016 at 6pm ?

Comment: take a look at the insights api for pages - "is it possible to do xy" is way too broad for stackoverflow, you have to do some research and testing first.